# Getting duplicate feeds after adding a new feed with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, rss, asihttprequest

I am developing an app that shows feeds from multiple websites in a tableview where the user can add additional feeds.

I created the app based on the following  [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial) using ASIHTTPRequest.

So, my problem is that after I add a new link, after the refresh method i get duplicate posts from all sources.

Here's my viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title =@"Lajmet";
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.allEntries = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    self.feeds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://pcworld.al/feed",@"http://geek.com/feed", @"http://feeds.feedburner.com/Mobilecrunch",@"http://zeri.info/rss/rss-5.xml", 
                  nil];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [self refresh];


}
```

The refresh methods looks like this:

```
-(void)refresh
{
    for (NSString *feed in _feeds)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:feed];
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [_queue addOperation:request];
    }
}
```

In this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2fSz.jpg) you can see how the application looks like and how the add screen works for new sources. I configured the done button so that it adds automatically one feed to test if it works.

```
-(void)addSourcesViewController:(AddSourcesViewController *)controller didAddSource:(RSSEntry *)source
{    
    Source *newSource = [[Source alloc] init];
    newSource.name = @"Test";
    newSource.link = @"http://lajmeshqip.com/feed";
    [self.feeds addObject:newSource.link];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.feeds);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [self refresh];

}
```

So my problem is that after hitting the done button, all entries are duplicated and they are shown in the tableview. I tried to use `[self.tableView reloadData];`instead of `[self refresh];`in the last method but then the new link doesn't appear at all.

Is there a way to load the last entry using ASIHTTPRequest or any tip i can follow? I am new and don't know which approach to follow. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Granit

Comment: Would be useful if you add the DelegateMethod of ASIHTTP to know what you are doing with your downloaded data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the cellRows are created from self.allEntries. So if you add a new Source to your self.feeds, before you download clean your self.allEntries array `[self.allEntries removeAllObjects];` because in your refresh method you are already reloading all feeds. After finishing the downloads reload your tableview data.